# React-hot-loader: react--dom patch is not detected

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, react-hot-loader

I updated some npm packages in my Gatsby project and now I'm seeing this warning in console:

`React-hot-loader: react--dom patch is not detected. React 16.6+ features may not work.`

However, when I look into the source code, there is a comment:

`// Actually everything works...`

What does this warning actually mean? Is this something I should fix or just let it be?

Comment: I noticed the same

Comment: it might be related to https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/1088

Comment: Seeing this issue as well. It kinda seems like it's looking for this package:
https://github.com/hot-loader/react-dom

Answer (score 17):

Per my comment above, it's looking like `react-hot-loader` wants the `@hot-loader/react-dom` package instead of standard `react-dom`:

- https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader#react--dom
- https://github.com/hot-loader/react-dom

Personally I'm a little concerned with swapping that out though since `react-dom` is a core part of any `react`-based application. Also it seems based on some of the linked issues and code comments that maybe this is just a short-term workaround to support new react features like hooks.

So I guess there's two options:

- Wait a little longer to see if they drop that requirement (and maybe run into a few edge cases for hot loading).
- Follow the [instructions](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader#react--dom) to get rid of the warning.

**Update**

You can disable the warning like so:

```js
import { hot, setConfig } from 'react-hot-loader'

setConfig({
    showReactDomPatchNotification: false
})
```

Comment: @gaearon is a developer of React, so there's no reason to be remotely concerned about swapping out `react-dom` for the alternative

See: https://github.com/gaearon/

Comment: First, my comment was less that it should be a security concern and more that I don't want a use a fork of a core package (e.g. they might forget to keep it up to date). Second, while that package is still under his namespace, @gaearon is _not_ the current maintainer. See the [latest contributor graphs](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/graphs/contributors?from=2016-12-27&to=2019-09-21&type=c).

Comment: A valid point that he's not the one committing most of the recent code, but @gaearon wouldn't host it under his name unless he had faith in doing that. The idea that they might forget to update a package with 11k stars, hosted where it is a bit absurd to me. [Lastly, he's very involved in the comments, even if not in the commits](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues?q=commenter%3Agaearon).

Comment: Fair points, though I wouldn't necessarily [conflate stars with update frequency](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/releases). Also the fork itself only [has ~70 stars](https://github.com/hot-loader/react-dom) which might suggest not many are using it. Anyway, I think your comments give a fair argument for the other approach. Are you suggesting I edit the answer? I did say "personally" and I kinda still feel that way despite your critique (fair as it is).

Comment: @SkipJack is there anyway to do this if you're using `import {hot} from 'react-hot-loader/root'? The docs recommend using the newer root import since it is much more resilient to JS errors.

https://github.com/cdharris/react-app-rewire-hot-loader

Comment: @ekfuhrmann yeah, it looks like you can just separate the `import` statements into `import { setConfig } from 'react-hot-loader'` and `import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader/root'`.

Answer (score 11):

You need to add [`@hot-loader/react-dom`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hot-loader/react-dom) to your project based on your ReactJS version, pay attention below command:

```
yarn add @hot-loader/react-dom@[YOUR_REACT_VERSION]
```

Then it is needed to add resolve alias for it on your Webpack configuration file:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
      'react-dom': '@hot-loader/react-dom'
    }
}
```

For more information read its [docs](https://github.com/hot-loader/react-dom).

Answer (score 10):

### Update 2020

**As of summer 2020**, this is the current solution recommended on [Gatsby's GitHub repository](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/11934#issuecomment-646966955):

#### Step 1

Run this command - But running this alone won't fix the issue:

```
npm install -D @hot-loader/react-dom
// or
yarn add -D @hot-loader/react-dom
```

#### Step 2

Modify `gatsby-node.js` to add the following:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, actions }) => {
  if (stage.startsWith("develop")) {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      resolve: {
        alias: {
          "react-dom": "@hot-loader/react-dom",
        },
      },
    })
  }
}
```

Restart `gatsby develop`. The warning is gone.

Answer (score 5):

So this appears to be an artifact of the development process. Looks like there was some back-and-forth on what to do in this case. The error message was commented out, and then later added back as a fix for an issue: https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/commit/efc3d6b5a58df77f6e0d5ca21bef54e8f8732070.

So, it looks like it's a minor warning, and you may be just fine unless you need specific features.

It might be a good idea to ask for clarity on this from the maintainers, since they seem slightly confused themselves :)

Answer (score 3):

In short - React-Hot-Loader is something that "might not work". It has a lot of problems and limitations.

"hot-patch" was created to (first) support new React features, and (second) make it more *stable*.

- Without this patch - something really *might* not work.
- With the patch - something might work better, especially in the future.

It's the only our(ok, mine) hope to mitigate the major problems RHL has, and tracked as "version 5" - https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/milestone/3

`hot-loader/react-dom` is not a "third party" lib - it's the same `react-dom` with some patches applied to `dev mode` only (you might check build scripts).

It just moves some dark magic, RHL uses to work, inside react, and actually removes it. RHL == black magic. RHL + patch == twice less magic.

Answer (score 2):

### Update late 2020

in **step 1**, you should run it as follow:

```
npm i @hot-loader/react-dom@YOUR_REACT_VERSION
```

because gatsby uses react version ^16.12.0, and running the command above without specifying react version with install ^17.0.1 which is not compatible with the ^16.x version.