# Gatsby application does not render on edge, ie. [ HTML1300, SCRIPT5009: SCRIPT5009: 'PerformanceObserver' is not defined ]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, microsoft-edge, gatsby

---

I ran into a problem opening the website I made using gatsby.js.
The problem is only on browsers: ie, edge (I tested Firefox, chrome, ie, edge)

First, the browser shows the whole rendered page then it destroys the layout for some reason.
The exception in the console is:

`1-time: HTML1300,
2-times: ReferenceError: 'PerformanceObserver' is not defined, 
1-time: SCRIPT5009: SCRIPT5009: 'PerformanceObserver' is not defined`

Also any tips on how to update this project because it shows me some warnings in local production. I looked in the gatsby docs for a while but I cannot find anything. Sorry for the dumb questions but kinda a newbie at React, gatsby...
Errors:

> React-Hot-Loader: react--dom patch is not detected. React 16.6+ features may not work. 
>       in AppContainer (created by HotExportedIndexPage)
>       in HotExportedIndexPage (created by PageRenderer)
>       in PageRenderer (at json-store.js:93)
>       in JSONStore (at root.js:51)
>       in RouteHandler (at root.js:73)
>       in EnsureResources (at root.js:61)
>       in LocationHandler (at root.js:119)
>       in LocationProvider (created by Context.Consumer)
>       in Context.Consumer (created by Location)
>       in Location (at root.js:118)
>       in Root (at root.js:127) backend.js:6:2315
>
> Warning: componentWillMount has been renamed, and is not recommended
>   for use. See react-unsafe-component-lifecycles for
>   details.
>
> - Move code with side effects to componentDidMount, and set initial state in the constructor.
> - Rename componentWillMount to UNSAFE_componentWillMount to suppress this warning in non-strict mode. In React 17.x, only the UNSAFE_ name
>     will work. To rename all deprecated lifecycles to their new names, you
>     can run `npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles` in your project
>     source folder. Preziranje nepodprtih entryTypes: paint.
>     gatsby-browser.js:15

Please update the following components: SideEffect(NullComponent) backend.js:6:2315

Any insight or help into this mystery is very appreciated

---

[Here is the link to my google drive folder where I pasted gatsby config files. If you need any other info about the page I will gladly provide the necessary information.](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_jDvvaRdhQ-wxUwhCxI2HJ42qKHfILSO?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

With refer to [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceObserver), we can see that the PerformanceObserver doesn't support IE and Edge browser.

> React-Hot-Loader: react--dom patch is not detected.

About this issue, please check the webpack config, perhaps you need to use "@hot-loader/react-dom", instead of "react-dom". more detail information, please check [this thread](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/1227) and [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54770535/react-hot-loader-react-dom-patch-is-not-detected).

Besides, I suggest you check the package.json file and check the [Gatsby Browser support](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-support/).